# Cannot access ActionController::Parameters no matter what I try

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

No idea why I can't access these params which are of class ActionController::Parameters. Here are the params:

```
{"{\"base_options\":{\"origin\":{\"name\":\"\",\"phone\":\"\",\"street_1\":\"\",\
"street_2\":\"\",\"zip\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state_iso2\":\"\",\"country_iso2\":\
"US\",\"address_type\":\"commercial\"},\"destination\":{\"name\":\"\",\"phone\":\"\",
\"street_1\":\"932 MyStreet Dr\",\"street_2\":\"\",\"zip\":\"12345\",\"city\":\"Mecio\",
\"state_iso2\":\"NX\",\"country_iso2\":\"US\",\"address_type\":\"residential\"},
\"items\":"=><ActionController::Parameters {"{\"sku\":\"\",\"name\":\"\",
\"length\":{\"units\":\"in\",\"value\":0},\"width\":{\"units\":\"in\",\"value\":0},
\"height\":{\"units\":\"in\",\"value\":0},\"weight\":{\"units\":\"oz\",\"value\":10},
\"discounted_price\":{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"amount\":\"0\"},
\"declared_value\":{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"amount\":\"17.5\"},\"quantity\":1,
\"attributes\":"=>[{"}"=>{",\"customer\":{\"customer_groups\":"=>{"\"\""=>{"},\"cart_id\":\"05\"},
\"connection_options\":{\"auth_token\":\"adfasdf\",\"seller_id\":\"asdf\",\"marketplace\":\"5\"}
,\"zone_options\":"=>[{",\"rate_options\":"=>[{"}"=>nil}]}]}}}}]} permitted: false>, 
"controller"=>"welcome", "action"=>"amazon_creds"}
```

I'm trying to get the sku, but all I ever get is `nil` with anything I try. I've tried the following:

```
params[:sku]
params["sku"]
params[:base_options][:sku]
params.as_json[:base_options]
params.as_json[:sku]
params.to_h[:sku]
params.to_unsafe_h.slice(:base_options)
params.to_unsafe_h[:sku]
params[0]
```

And yes I've read this [ActionContoller::Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)

Yea I'm at a loss here, no idea how to access these `params`. Anyone out there put me out of my misery?

Comment: what is the result of `params.to_h.keys?`

Comment: I don't have any `params` whitelisted yet, so I did this `params.to_unsafe_h.keys` and got the keys.. which look like this: ["{\"base_options\":{\"origin\":{\"name\":\"\",\"phone\":\"\",\"street_1\":\"\",\"street_2\":\"\",\"zip\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"state_iso2\":\"\",\"country_iso2\":\"US\",\"address_type\":\"commercial\"},\"destination\":{\"name\":\"\",\"phone\":\"\",\"street_1\":\"933 Nottingham Dr\",\"street_2\":\"\",\"zip\":\"28211\",\"city\":\"Charlotte\",\"state_iso2\":\"NC\",\"country_iso2\":\"US\",\"address_type\":\"residential\"},\"items\":", "controller", "action"]

Comment: Are you interacting with AWS here? The `"action"=>"amazon_creds"` suggests you are. AWS likes JSON so much that it often encodes JSON inside JSON so you might have to dig the right thing out of `params` and then manually `JSON.parse` it, and then dig out your SKU.

Comment: so it is as it appears from the paste in your question ... the keys of `params` are JSON encoded strings for some reason. This seems really wierd to me - where is this request coming from?

Comment: Well these params are actually coming from BigCommerce. I'm wondering if somehow they just aren't right. I'm not sure at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will automatically populate the params hash with the deserialized request body if the `Content-Type` request header is set to `application/json`. It appears that the header is missing for this request. We're adding the appropriate header now.